# pandas rolling mean excluding zeros

Tags: pandas, mean, rolling-computation

How can I efficiently calculate a rolling mean excluding zeros for a given time window?

My try:

```py
window = 5
df['rollMeanColumn'] = df.loc[:, 'Column'].rolling(window).apply(lambda x: x[x!=0].mean())
```

This code seems to work but for longer datasets is extremely slow

Can I improve it?

Comment: There is this little trick where you can convert your `0` to `NaN` by running this `df.replace(0, np.NaN)`. Pandas `mean` by default excludes missing values for computation, thus, you can take advantage of this rather than using `apply`; because `apply` method has known to be slower. Also, if you are working with large datasets and open to open-source program, you should take a look at PySpark specifically on Pandas API.

Comment: Maybe a np approach would be wise here like sliding_window_view

Comment: added a solution. does it help?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng(92)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':rng.integers(0,5, 10),
                   'b':rng.integers(0,5, 10),
                   'c':rng.integers(0,5, 10)})
df
###
   a  b  c
0  2  3  1
1  3  4  0
2  4  1  1
3  0  0  1
4  2  3  3
5  1  0  2
6  2  2  2
7  1  3  2
8  3  0  3
9  0  0  2
```

```
df['rollMeanColumn_a'] = df[df['a'] != 0]['a'].rolling(window=3).mean()
df['rollMeanColumn_b'] = df['b'].replace(0,np.nan).dropna().rolling(window=3).mean()
df['rollMeanColumn_c'] = df.query('c != 0')['c'].rolling(3).mean()
df
###
   a  b  c  rollMeanColumn_a  rollMeanColumn_b  rollMeanColumn_c
0  2  3  1               NaN               NaN               NaN
1  3  4  0               NaN               NaN               NaN
2  4  1  1          3.000000          2.666667               NaN
3  0  0  1               NaN               NaN          1.000000
4  2  3  3          3.000000          2.666667          1.666667
5  1  0  2          2.333333               NaN          2.000000
6  2  2  2          1.666667          2.000000          2.333333
7  1  3  2          1.333333          2.666667          2.000000
8  3  0  3          2.000000               NaN          2.333333
9  0  0  2               NaN               NaN          2.333333
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it. If you post the data to reproduce, i would have posted the result set.

```
window=5

df[df['Column']!=0]['Column'].rolling(window).mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @JK Chai

```
window=5
df['rollMeanColumn'] = df.loc[:, 'Column'].replace(0,np.nan).rolling(window).mean()
```